# How do I push to an array within an array in a collection with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `User schema` created with Mongoose that holds a `customer` array, and inside that `customer` array there is another `fleet` array. I have figured out how to push to the `customer` array within the `User schema`, however I can not figure out how to loop through the customers, find the `customer` via id or name, and then push data into the `fleet` array.

Here is my `User schema`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    registerDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    customer: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            default: 'No email addresses found',
        },
        fleet: [{
            unitType: {
                type: String,
                default: 'No type selected',
            },
            unitNumber: {
                type: String,
                default: 'No unit number provided',
            },
            vinNumber: {
                type: String,
                default: 'No vin number provided'
            },
        }]
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I was able to figure out how to push a new customer into the `customer` array no problem. My problem is I do not get how I can loop through the `customer` array, and once I find the `customer` that I need, push data into the `fleet` array. I am really just stumped on how to word my Google search! Hopefully this is detailed enough, and please let me know if you need to see any other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use positional **'$'** operation. Read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays)

```
UserSchema.update(
    {'customer.email':'xyz@email.com'},
    {
        $push:{
            'customer.$.fleet':<fleet object>
        }
    },function(err,result){

    })
```

---   OR   ---

```
UserSchema.update(
    {'customer.email':'xyz@email.com'},
    {
        $set:{
             'customer.$.fleet':[fleet array]
        }
    },function(err,result){

    })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the examples and link.